# Group By timespan in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

Let's suppose we have a class like:

```
    class Forecast
    {
      int LocationId;
      int DepartmentId;
      DateTime StartDate;
      DateTime EndDate;
      int CountOfEmployees;
    }
```

I have a list of Forecasts: `List<Forecasts> forecasts`

The list is grouped by a 15 minute interval, for example:

```
forecast[0] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 06:15:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 2  }
forecast[1] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:15:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 06:30:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 1  }
forecast[2] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:30:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 06:45:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 3  }
forecast[3] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:45:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 1  }
forecast[4] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:15:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 2  }
forecast[5] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:15:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:30:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 2  }
forecast[6] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:30:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:45:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 5 }
forecast[7] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:45:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 08:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 3  }
forecast[8] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 06:15:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 2  }
forecast[9] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:15:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 06:30:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 1  }
forecast[10] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:30:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 06:45:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 3  }
forecast[11] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:45:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 1  }
forecast[12] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:15:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 2  }
forecast[13] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:15:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:30:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 2  }
forecast[14] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:30:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:45:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 5 }
forecast[15] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:45:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 08:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 3  }
```

I would want the result to be grouped in a time interval of 60 minutes, Location and Department along with summation of countOfEmployees. So the expected result should be something like this:

```
result[0] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 06:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 7  }
result[1] = new Forecast { LocationId = 1, DepartmentId = 1, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 08:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 12  }
result[2] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 08:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 12  }
result[3] = new Forecast { LocationId = 2, DepartmentId = 2, StartTime = 2018-10-01 07:00:00.000, EndTime = 2018-10-01 08:00:00.000, CountOfEmployees = 12  }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: When you are creating examples in question, please at least make sure that someone can copy paste your code and it will compile, so he will not have to think about syntax correctness.

Comment: Also `result[2]` value in your example is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use linq `select` with `group by`

Establish a time grouping in linq `GroupBy` for your logic for `EndTime`, `StartTime`, `LocationId`

`StartTime` and `EndTime` for each hour.

```
var result = forecast
.GroupBy(_ => new {
    _.LocationId,
    StartTime = new DateTime(_.StartTime.Year,
                              _.StartTime.Month,
                              _.StartTime.Day,
                              _.StartTime.Hour,0,0,0),
    EndTime = new DateTime(_.StartTime.Year,
                              _.StartTime.Month,
                              _.StartTime.Day,
                              _.StartTime.Hour + 1, 0, 0, 0)
})
.Select(x => new {
    x.Key.LocationId,
    x.Key.StartTime,
    x.Key.EndTime,
    CountOfEmployees = x.Sum(y=>y.CountOfEmployees)});
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pUrdZz)

**Result**

```
LocationId : 1 StartTime : 10/1/2018 6:00:00 AM EndTime : 10/1/2018 7:00:00 AM  CountOfEmployees : 7
LocationId : 1 StartTime : 10/1/2018 7:00:00 AM EndTime : 10/1/2018 8:00:00 AM  CountOfEmployees : 12
LocationId : 2 StartTime : 10/1/2018 6:00:00 AM EndTime : 10/1/2018 7:00:00 AM  CountOfEmployees : 7
LocationId : 2 StartTime : 10/1/2018 7:00:00 AM EndTime : 10/1/2018 8:00:00 AM  CountOfEmployees : 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar, assuming that your interval will always start at 00 mins to 60 mins, and not from say, 6:15 to 7:15.

```
var result = forecast.GroupBy(x=>new {x.StartTime.Hour, x.LocationId, x.DepartmentId})
                    .Select(x=> new Forecast
                                { 
                                    LocationId = x.Key.LocationId, 
                                    DepartmentId = x.Key.DepartmentId, 
                                    StartTime =  x.ToList().OrderBy(e=>e.StartTime).First().StartTime,
                                    EndTime =  x.ToList().OrderBy(e=>e.EndTime).Last().EndTime,
                                    CountOfEmployees = x.ToList().Sum(c=>c.CountOfEmployees) 
                                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. As @SeM mentioned, you need to show your research. Your question did not show any work.

```
var results = from foreCastSelector in foreCasts
          group foreCastSelector by new
          {
              LocationId = foreCastSelector.LocationId,
              DepartmentId = foreCastSelector.DepartmentId,
              StartDate = foreCastSelector.StartDate.AddMinutes(-1 * foreCastSelector.StartDate.Minute),
              EndDate = foreCastSelector.StartDate.AddMinutes(-1 * foreCastSelector.StartDate.Minute).AddHours(1)
          } into gcs
          select new Forecast
          {
              LocationId = gcs.Key.LocationId,
              DepartmentId = gcs.Key.DepartmentId,
              StartDate = gcs.Key.StartDate,
              EndDate = gcs.Key.EndDate,
              CountOfEmployees = gcs.Sum(r => r.CountOfEmployees)
              };

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.LocationId + " | " + result.DepartmentId + " | "
        + result.StartDate.ToString() + " | "
       + result.EndDate.ToString() + " | "
       + result.CountOfEmployees);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove minutes from times, then group by new `StartTime`:

```
var result = forecast
.GroupBy(g => new { StartTime = g.StartTime.Date.AddHours(g.StartTime.Hour), g.LocationId, g.DepartmentId })
.Select(s => 
    new Forecast()
    {
        LocationId = s.Key.LocationId,
        DepartmentId = s.Key.DepartmentId,
        StartTime = s.Key.StartTime,
        EndTime = s.Max(m => m.EndTime),
        CountOfEmployees = s.Sum(c => c.CountOfEmployees),
    }
)
.OrderBy(o => o.LocationId)
.ThenBy(o => o.DepartmentId)
.ThenBy(o => o.StartTime)
.ToList();
```

Or with query syntax:

```
var q = from f in forecast
        group f by new 
        { 
            StartTime = f.StartTime.Date.AddHours(f.StartTime.Hour), 
            f.LocationId, 
            f.DepartmentId 
        } into g
        orderby g.Key.LocationId, g.Key.DepartmentId, g.Key.StartTime
        select new Forecast
        {
            LocationId = g.Key.LocationId,
            DepartmentId = g.Key.DepartmentId,
            StartTime = g.Key.StartTime,
            EndTime = g.Max(m => m.EndTime),
            CountOfEmployees = g.Sum(s => s.CountOfEmployees)
        };
```

output:

```
LocationId: 1, DepartmentId: 1, StartTime: 10/1/2018 6:00:00, EndTime: 10/1/2018 7:00:00, CountOfEmployees: 7
LocationId: 1, DepartmentId: 1, StartTime: 10/1/2018 7:00:00, EndTime: 10/1/2018 8:00:00, CountOfEmployees: 12
LocationId: 2, DepartmentId: 2, StartTime: 10/1/2018 6:00:00, EndTime: 10/1/2018 7:00:00, CountOfEmployees: 7
LocationId: 2, DepartmentId: 2, StartTime: 10/1/2018 7:00:00, EndTime: 10/1/2018 8:00:00, CountOfEmployees: 12
```

**[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJDTrb)**